# Error: PDF from XML in Java

Tags: java, apache-fop

I just found a code that could help in to transform an XML file to a PDF file but when i write the code i get  and ERROR:

Imports:

package PdfXml;

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import org.apache.fop.apps.FOPException;
import org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent;
import org.apache.fop.apps.Fop;
import org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory;
import org.apache.fop.apps.MimeConstants;
```

Error Section

```
public static void convertToPDF() throws IOException, FOPException, TransformerException {
                // the XSL FO file
                File xsltFile = new File(RESOURCES_DIR + "//template.xsl");
                // the XML file which provides the input
                StreamSource xmlSource = new StreamSource(new File(RESOURCES_DIR + "//data.xml"));
                // create an instance of fop factory
                FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(new File(".").toURI());
                // a user agent is needed for transformation
                FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();
                // Setup output
                OutputStream out;
                out = new java.io.FileOutputStream(OUTPUT_DIR + "//output.pdf");

                try {
                    // Construct fop with desired output format
                    Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, foUserAgent, out);

                    // Setup XSLT
                    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xsltFile));

                    // Resulting SAX events (the generated FO) must be piped through to
                    // FOP
                    Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());

                    // Start XSLT transformation and FOP processing
                    // That's where the XML is first transformed to XSL-FO and then
                    // PDF is created
                    transformer.transform(xmlSource, res);
                } finally {
                    out.close();
                }
            }
```

I get ERROR on "FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(new File(".").toURI());", exactly en newInstance : "The method newInstance() in the type FopFactory is not applicable for the arguments (URI)".

**Do i need to add a .jar ?**

java version: 1.8.0

Comment: `newInstance()`does not take any arguments.

Comment: Done, i put newInstance() witout arguments then i got this ERROR compling the code.: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlgraphics.xmp.Metadata.mergeInto(Lorg/apache/xmlgraphics/xmp/Metadata;)

Comment: Do you have all the required dependencies for xmlgraphics? Sounds like you're missing dependencies for FopFactory.

Comment: i just follow some tips to install apache fop and jar. How o where i can check the dependencies are missing ?

Comment: You would usually use a dependency manager like maven.

Comment: i just create a simple app without a pom.xml or something like that to test solutions... can i add some pom.xml to write dependency or it has to be like a maven project  and manage them ?

Comment: You can manually manage them by using the maven repo as a reference or write a pom. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlgraphics